# Logger not logging all events?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, logging

I am attempting to test some data structures by timing their add methods.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import edu.sdsu.cs.datastructures.LinkedList;
import edu.sdsu.cs.datastructures.SlowDeque;

public class DequeDriver<E> {
    final Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("***.****.**.DequeDriver");
    static FileHandler logFile;
    static SimpleFormatter formatterTxt;
    private Deque<E> dut;


    //              Construct the Deque and test it         //
    private DequeDriver() throws SecurityException, IOException {
        initLogger();
        myLogger.info("Running SlowDeque: ");
        dut = new SlowDeque<E>();
        runTest(dut);
        myLogger.info("Running with LinkedList: ");
        dut = new LinkedList<E>();
        runTest(dut);

    }
    //              Run tests on the Deque              //
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void runTest(Deque<E> dequeUnderTest){
        int testSize = 1000;
        long startTime;
        long endTime;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();;
            for(long a = 0; a < testSize * i; a++){
                dequeUnderTest.add((E) new Long(a));
            }
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            myLogger.info("Adding " + (i * testSize) + " items took: " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            new DequeDriver<Long>();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    void initLogger() throws SecurityException, IOException {
        disableConsoleLogger();
        logFile = new FileHandler("DequeDriver.xml");
        myLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        myLogger.addHandler(logFile);
    }
    void disableConsoleLogger() {
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        if (handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
          rootLogger.removeHandler(handlers[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

No matter how I change the testSize or output file name in the FileHandler() method, I still only get the "Running with..." output and two outputs from the runTests() method: One for 1000 and one for 10000 items.

Is there some aspect of this I am unfamiliar with? My IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: If you want to benchmark code you should really look at using JMH instead of rolling your own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code with replacing `SlowDeque` with `BlockingQueue` and the logging is working.

Make sure the implementation of `LinkedList` and `SlowDeque` are working as they need to.

`import edu.sdsu.cs.datastructures.LinkedList;
import edu.sdsu.cs.datastructures.SlowDeque;`

```
</record>
<record>
  <date>2016-03-24T13:06:36</date>
  <millis>1458846396265</millis>
  <sequence>9</sequence>
  <logger>DequeDriver</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>DequeDriver</class>
  <method>runTest</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Adding 9000 items took: 1512513 milliseconds.</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2016-03-24T13:06:36</date>
  <millis>1458846396267</millis>
  <sequence>10</sequence>
  <logger>DequeDriver</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>DequeDriver</class>
  <method>runTest</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Adding 10000 items took: 1547532 milliseconds.</message>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2016-03-24T13:06:36</date>
  <millis>1458846396267</millis>
  <sequence>11</sequence>
  <logger>DequeDriver</logger>
  <level>INFO</level>
  <class>DequeDriver</class>
  <method>&lt;init&gt;</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>Running with LinkedList: </message>
</record>
</log>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I fixed it though the problem was the libraries in eclipse. Once I reloaded them it worked perfectly.